# What is wrong with this NULL check for a ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, null

```
myCustomController *controller = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:page];

NSLog(@"%@",controller); // <- THIS RETURNS NULL IN CONSOLE

if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
 // Why is the above check not working if controller in console says it's null?
 // It's not jumping into this loop. Has something changed in iOS4.0 SDK?
}
```

what is wrong with this `null` check for a `viewController`, it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSLog` should return `(null)` (which probably is description for `nil`), not `NULL` in console. Your check should look like this:

```
if (!controller) {
  // do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `if (controller == nil)` (both are equally correct).

Comment: Except that you should never get nil out of an array. You can't store nils in arrays. That's what the NSNull class is for. On the other hand, you might get nil out of this if `myMutableArray` itself is nil.